# Python sorting dictionary by key returning list of values itemgetter

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Are these two functions that create `x` equivalent? I don't understand why itemgetter seems to return the correct variable when using `0` as an input in this case.

Is itemgetter correctly sorting by dictionary key?. They both print the same

```
from operator import itemgetter

lvls = {1: ["t1","t2"], 2: ["t3","t4"], 3: ["tdfgdf99","x99"]}

x = sorted((v for k,v in lvls.items()),key=itemgetter(0),reverse=True)

print (x)

x = sorted((v for k,v in lvls.items()),key=lambda k: k,reverse=True)

print (x)
```

Comment: do you know how `itemgetter` works? in your scenario you specify `0` as the argument for `itemgetter`. It is going to return the keys sorted by `f(lvls.items()[0])` where in this case `f` is `v for k,v` so it's sorting based on `lvls.values()[0]` in reverse. hope that helps

Comment: @new_to_coding your approach is basically giving the same results, by fluke, if you are attempting to sort them by keys i.e. 1, 2, 3. In a very different scenario of values in your dictionary these two sorted calls might return entirely different sequences.

Comment: No. Both of those sorts _totally ignore_ the keys of `lvls` and are only looking at the associated values. The 1st one is sorting by the 1st item in each value list, the second one uses all items in each value list. BTW, `lambda k: k` is equivalent to the default key function, only slower.

Comment: nvm, thanks all, I've found another question on how

Comment: Sure. But it would be better if your sample data was different, so we could see the difference between sorting on the key and those sorts you've already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itemgetter(0)` gets the item at `0th` index.

In your first case, you are sorting `0th` indexes of `v` in reverse order. So basically what you are actually doing is sorting `0th` indexes of ["t1", "t2"], ["t3", "t4"] and ["tdfgdf99","x99"] in reverse order.

In your second case, you are sorting `v` which is list values - basically `[["t1","t2"], ["t3, "t4"], ["tdfgdf99","x99"]]` as is in reverse order. the purpose of `lambda k: k` is you are simply picking one element from this list and returning.